# Paypal - TRANSACTION_REFUSED when using japan currency on Android

Tags: android, paypal

When I make a order on Android platform. The **country of sandbox account (Personal)** is 'JP - japan' and the Business account(xxx-facilitator) is 'US'. If I use personal account to make a order, then SDK will refuse the order. The message is following:

> {"name":"TRANSACTION_REFUSED","message":"The request was
>   refused","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#TRANSACTION_REFUSED","debug_id":"2fe4f6f8903f1"}

However, if I use a **personal account with country "US"**, then the payment is fine.
So, I don't understand why I cannot use **JP account** to make a order.
PS: I already add "Japanese Yen" into my facilitator account on "[Manage Currencies](https://www.sandbox.paypal.com)"().

Anyone can help ?

Comment: Can you check your Japanese personal account is having a confirmed bank account link to it ?

Comment: @Eshan Does you mean even this is only **sandbox account**, it should also have a confirmed bank account to link? And where I need to check, [developer paypal](http://developer.paypal.com/) or [Sandbox paypal](http://www.sandbox.paypal.com/)?

Comment: @Eshan Yes, thanks. I found the account doesn't link to to bank account. Maybe this is why I cannot make a order. thanks. I will check it.

Comment: Correct because when I checked your sandbox account it shows that the bank attached to the sandbox account is not confirmed , You can try to add the any random bank information and it should work after that .

Comment: Possibly due to strict banking rules in Japan like this: https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/About-Settings-Archive/New-JAPAN-rules-for-upload-of-Zairyu-or-Alien-Registration-Card/td-p/561382